# Hibernate recreates join table when adding to List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

I have a Story containing a list of Comment, mapped with a JoinTable.
I noticed that every time I add a new Comment to the list, hibernate deletes and recreates all entries in the join table related to the story.
I'd expect it to just add a new row to the table.
In the code below, the save methods are implemented by Spring Data.
Am I missing something?
Thank you.

**Story.java:**

```
@Entity
public class Story implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name="UserComment", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Story_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Comment_id"))
    private List<Comment> userComments;
    ...
```

**Comment.java:**

```
@Entity
public class Comment implements Serializable {
...
```

**Adding a new Comment:**

```
Comment comment = new Comment();
comment.setContent(content);
commentRepository.save(comment);
story.getUserComments().add(comment);
storyRepository.save(story);
```

**Hibernate log on the storyRepository.save(story) execution:**

```
Hibernate: delete from UserComment where Story_id=?
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) values (?, ?)
```

**Library versions:**

- Hibernate 4.3.5
- Spring Data JPA 1.6.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the expected behavior for a unidirectional bag used. According to [Hibernate Anti-Patterns][1]:

> The bag semantics has the worst performance when it comes to the
>   number of operations since it always re-creates the entire collection.
>   Hibernate issues a delete statement to remove all associations of the
>   old collection from the association table. Then, it issues N inserts
>   to add all associations representing the new collection to the
>   association table. Hibernate does not analyze how many elements have
>   been changed in the collection.

1. You can optimize it by turning it into an id-bag, which is an indexed List.
2. You can map the UserComment mapping having 2 @ManyToOne associations to both Story and Comment, so your bag will turned into a mappedBy bidirectional bag which is much more efficient than its unidirectional counterpart (because the mappedBy bag won't control the association, since it will be the @ManyToOne side to propagate state transitions to SQL statements).

Comment: Am I the only one to think that, with so many gotchas, we should be better off without hibernate-managed associations? I'm going to write a simple native query to add the comment to the list.

Comment: My advice is to keep it simple.

Comment: As simple as it is to write my own query, why should I change my model to adapt to the persistence engine idiosyncrasies? @Query(value="insert into UserComment (Story_id, Comment_id) VALUES (:storyId, :commentId)", nativeQuery = true)

Comment: It was a general advice. A native query will work but it will require a change whenever you add a new field. Using a bidirectional association is simple and more flexible. But it requires a mapping change.